# InvalidOperationException thrown in Http post when try to create HttpContent

Tags: c#, http, post

I've made an application which would need to Post data through http to a url, below is the code on how I post data:

```c#
using(System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()) {
    //Initialize a HttpClient
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(strURL);
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    FormUrlEncodedContent formUrlEncodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(convertNameValueCollectionToKeyValuePair(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(objPostData.ToString())));
    //This is where I got stuck
    System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<FormUrlEncodedContent> (formUrlEncodedContent, new System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());


    using(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(strAddr, content).Result) {}
}

protected static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> convertNameValueCollectionToKeyValuePair(NameValueCollection input) {
    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    foreach(var key in input.AllKeys) {
        values.Add(
        new KeyValuePair<string, string> (key, input[key]));
    }

    return values.AsEnumerable();
}
```

The code runs smoothly until it ran into this line:

```
  System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<FormUrlEncodedContent>(formUrlEncodedContent, new System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());
```

The exception `The configured formatter 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter' cannot write an object of type 'FormUrlEncodedContent'.` flows

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh I figured it out...

I changed the method of creating the HttpContent...

```
using(System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()) {
    //Initialize a HttpClient
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(strURL);
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    //I changed this line.
    System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(convertNameValueCollectionToKeyValuePair(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(objPostData.ToString()));

    using(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(strAddr, content).Result) {}
}
```